# How to get JSON response using RESTful webservice in spring 3.1

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I want to generate a JSON response of my object I write code for that but not getting success it is giving error 406 I am not using maven I am using ant

This is my controller

```
@Controller

public class LoginRestCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public  Employee checklogin(){
        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setEmailId("sdosi@cur.com");
        e.setId(1);
        e.setPassword("a");

        return e;

    }

}
```

This is my configuration file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
       <property name="definitions">
         <list>
           <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
         </list>
       </property>
     </bean>

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="viewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
     </bean> 

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




</beans>
```

I am calling as `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/test` but getting error 406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following to produce `JSON Rsponse`. You would require `Gson` library, and the `controller` would look as follows:

```
@Controller
public class LoginRestCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public  String checklogin(){
        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setEmailId("sdosi@cur.com");
        e.setId(1);
        e.setPassword("a");
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String jsonResponse=gson.toJson(e);
        return jsonResponse;

    }

}
```

**Json response** looks as following:

```
{"emailId":"sdosi@cur.com","id":1,"password":"a"}
```

Comment: This is ok but is  there any another way with jakson

Comment: You can use Jackson instead of Gson, both will work. However I prefer to use Gson.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to put jackson dependencies in your pom.xml if they are not already there.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

If they are already there can you update your RequestMapping with

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
```

This will ensure that we return a response with a json header.

Answer (score 2):

add the following dependencies in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

with in your spring configuration xml files add the following beans

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

now you can use your controller as it is

```
@Controller
public class LoginRestCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Employee checklogin() {
        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setEmailId("sdosi@cur.com");
        e.setId(1);
        e.setPassword("a");

        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I included jakson core, annotaion, databinding, mapper jars in my project if I include code in configuartion project wont get up give error 404 not found

Comment: try adding these jars into your application: 
jackson-core-asl (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.12/jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar), 
jackson-mapper-asl (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.12/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar), 
json (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar)

Comment: are you getting any exception in the server log, if you can post the execption log then that would be helpful